# difference between member and method on msdn website?

Tags: c#, msdn

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb351562.aspx
when you goto that page on the left side it has links to "members" and "methods" of the class but look the same to me. is there a difference?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A "member" is anything inside the class or interface, so this includes methods, fields, properties, subtypes and maybe more. At the bottom of the page you link to, you'll notice that the properties are missing on the methods page.